Standardizing LiDAR processing for meter and feet projections: lidR package
I am creating an R script with multiple different types of LiDAR data, some in a meters projection and some in feet. I therefore need to convert some of the units in my script from meters to feet in order to make the outputs standardized. (I am using trying to avoid re-projecting the actual pointcloud data and am instead changing the distance units in the processing steps.) I am using the lidR package (ver 4.1.1).
The processing steps are:
1). remove outliers
2). Height normalize
3). Voxelize
4). Create output rasters using catalog_map
Some conversions seem straightforward, such as setting the chunk sizes for my LAScatalog objects.
# Meters
opt_chunk_size(LAScatalog) <- 250
# Feet
opt_chunk_size(LAScatalog) <- 820.21 

However, for height normalization I am unsure if the "rmax" in the knnidw function is in the units of the input data (either meters or feet) OR if the radius is "units" of pointcloud points. The documentation states that the default is 50 units but it doesn't specify if those are units of distance or of LiDAR points.
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lidR/versions/3.1.3/topics/knnidw
If "rmax" does use the units of the input data, my thought would be to convert meters to feet like so:
# Step 2, height normalize
# Meters
LiDAR_norm <- normalize_height(LAScatalog, tin(extrapolate = knnidw(k = 10, p = 2, rmax = 50)))
# Feet
LiDAR_norm <- normalize_height(LAScatalog, tin(extrapolate = knnidw(k = 10, p = 2, rmax = 164.042)))

My other steps will look as follows:
# Step 3. Voxelize
# Meters
vox <- voxelize_points(LAScatalog, 2.5)
# Feet
vox <- voxelize_points(LAScatalog, 8.2021)

# Step 4. raster metrics
# Meters
metrics <- catalog_map(LAScatalog, 
                       apply_vert_configuration, # Custom function: FEET 
                       res = 5,
                       .options = options)
# Feet
metrics <- catalog_map(LAScatalog, 
                       apply_vert_configuration_FT, # Custom function: FEET 
                       res = 16.4042,
                       .options = options)

Have I properly standardized from meters to feet, especially for Step 2, height normalize? If knnidw is unitless/uses pointcloud points as "units", then I would leave rmax the same between meters and feet.

lidR uses the units of the point cloud for every parameters that have a length dimension. The default values are in meters. To work in feet, you must change all the default values that have a length dimension, such as a resolution or a radius. 3 means 3 m if the point cloud is in meters and 3 feets is the point cloud is in feets.
Your approach is correct.

However, for height normalization I am unsure if the "rmax" in the knnidw function is in the units of the input data (either meters or feet) OR if the radius is "units" of pointcloud points.

The input data IS the point cloud. Thus, both are the same.

Thank you! Appreciate the confirmation.
